# Sharepoint 2010 Taxonomy: How to search for a term by custom property

Tags: taxonomy

Lets say I have a whole lot of Terms in the Term Store.

When I create the Term items I am setting a custom property like this:

```
Term term = termSet.CreateTerm("ParentTerm", 1029, new Guid("{0368F902-740B-4855-A4A7-FA8F96813CCB}"));
term.SetCustomProperty("OBJID", "2222"); 
termStore.CommitAll();
```

So far so good, but now how would I perform a search to find this particular term based on its custom property, in this case OBJID.

Is there built in search methods for terms?

There is the

```
TaxonomySession session = new TaxonomySession(site);
session.GetTerm("GUID_OF_TERM");
```

But this is not the same as the term custom property - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Check if this exists:

```
term.CustomProperties["key"]
```

Or if you want to check all of the Term Set:

```
termSet.Terms.Select(x => x.CustomProperties["key"] != null);
```

This could be made into a recursive function to check for all child terms.

Answer (score 1):

There is method called GetTermsWithCustomProperty in TaxonomySession and TermSet classes. Probably you can use that one.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.taxonomy.termstore.gettermswithcustomproperty.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.taxonomy.taxonomysession.gettermswithcustomproperty.aspx

Answer (score 0):

There is no out of the box functionality to search for this. You have to build some kind of recursive function to do this on your own - ultimatley you need to traverse all Terms, which likely would kill performance.

I would suggest you rethink your design.

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying the below code.  I use it to recursively find the first Tag that matches a Term label.  You would have to change the if statement to query for your custom property.

```
private Term GetChildTermThatMatchesName(Term sourceTerm, string name)
{

   Term  term = null;

   if (sourceTerm != null)
   {
      if (sourceTerm.TermsCount > 0)
      {
         if (sourceTerm.Terms.Any(t => t.Name == TaxonomyItem.NormalizeName(name)))
         {
            term =  sourceTerm.Terms.First(t => t.Name == TaxonomyItem.NormalizeName(name));
         }
         else
         {
            /* Recusively loop through child until we find our first match */
            foreach (Term childTerm in sourceTerm.Terms)
            {
               if (term == null)
               {
                  term = GetChildTermThatMatchesName(childTerm, name);
               }
               else
               {
                  break;
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }


   return term;
}
```